# How to make xtightvncviewer fullscreen

Tags: vnc

So I have a VNC server running on my windows laptop and I want to connect it to my Raspberry Pi in full-screen. I've been using:

xtightvncviewer -fullscreen

but all I get is this[image]

Is there any way I can force scale to always fill my display?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TightVNC viewer for Linux does not support scaling. You have to use a different viewer. You can use the forked-off ssvnc, which viewer has a scaling option.

http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/ssvnc.html

Comment: I can't get the scaling option to work. Do you have a working example command? I've tried `ssvnc -scale fit Vnc://1.2.3.4:5900`.

Comment: Try `SSVNC_SCALE=1.4 ssvnc 1.2.3.4:5900`. It seem both the -scale option and *fit* is somewhat tricky to use.

Comment: I noticed there is another binary called `ssvncviewer` which doesn't spawn that annoying GUI and also accepts the `-scale` option although fit/auto are somewhat misbehaving.

Comment: Try `ssvncviewer -scale $(xrandr|grep '*'|sed 's/^ *//'|cut -d' ' -f1|head -n1) localhost:5900`

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is very simple to do this.

When running the command to start the VNC server on your RPi, add the parameter for resolution.

EX:

If the resolution of your screen is 1920x1080, like mine is, then run:

`vncserver :0 -geometry 1920x1080 -depth 24`

This will start a VNC server at `[YOUR RPI IP ADDRESS]:0`

You can replace `1920` and `1080` with your screen's resolution.

Comment: Alright sweet but how can I do the same thing on my windows, my raspberry pi is just the client

Answer (score 1):

You can try steps given in [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=161813) thread. Adding the code here, for brevity. SSH into your Pi and enter the following:

```
sudo /boot/config.txt /boot/config.txt.bak
sudo nano /boot/config.txt
```

With the first command you are creating a backup of the original configuration. You can revert back to this if something malfunctions due to changes in the future. Then open nano, which is an editor and next make the following changes:

```
...
# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=16
...
```

After making the above changes you force your Pi to display in HDMI mode.

Note:

1. You need to remove "#" from the corresponding line to uncomment it
2. Nano is simple to use - just like notepad in Windows
3. Do save your file upon exit
4. reboot system `using sudo shutdown -r now`

It worked perfectly for me, I hope it goes well for you also.